# POST ARRAY Request java в okhttp

Tags: java, android, массивы, post, okhttp

Мне нужно отправить массив на сервер(ЭТО НЕ JSON), использую okhttp

```
[answers] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [answer_id] => 4648
            [duration_time_question] => 0
            [text_open_answer] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [answer_id] => 4650
            [duration_time_question] => 0
            [text_open_answer] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [answer_id] => 4667
            [duration_time_question] => 1
            [text_open_answer] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [answer_id] => 4652
            [duration_time_question] => 1
            [text_open_answer] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [answer_id] => 4678
            [duration_time_question] => 0
            [text_open_answer] => 
        )
```

Для примера мне дали такой кусочек синтаксиса на php. Проблем с отправкой пары ключ-значение нет, но не знаю как быть с массивом.
Этот код непосредственно отправка.

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.newCall(new DoRequest().Post(dictionary, getIntent().getExtras().getString("url"), array))
                .enqueue(new Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("Failed");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                        String temp = response.body().string();

                        System.out.println("Success " + temp);

                    }


                });
```

А этот формирование корректного request

```
public Request Post(Dictionary<String, String> dictionary, String url, Dictionary<String, String> data) {
    RequestBody formBody = null;
    Dictionary<String, String> array = new Hashtable<>();
    switch (dictionary.get("name_form")) {
        case "questionnaire":
            formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("name_form", "questionnaire")
                    .add("login_admin", dictionary.get("login_admin"))
                    .add("login", dictionary.get("login"))
                    .add("sess_passw", dictionary.get("passw"))
                    .add("sess_login", dictionary.get("login"))
                    .add("project_id", "77")
                    .add("questionnaire_id", "67")
                    .add("user_project_id", "399")
                    .add("date_interview", "2017-01-22 14:57:41")
                    .add("gps", "53.69595:23.8204:0:50:1485086208.158")
                    .add("cell", "")
                    .add("duration_time_questionnaire", "")
                    .build();

           for (int i = 0; i < array.size() / 3; i++) {
                formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                        .add("answers["+i+"]", array.get("answer_id"))
                        .add("answers["+i+"]", array.get("duration_time_question"))
                        .add("answers["+i+"]", array.get("text_open_answer"))
                        .build();
            }


            break;

    }
    return new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(formBody).build();
}
```

Comment: так а кто мешает его в json преобразовать?

Comment: У вас какая то каша. То, что в самом первом листинге - это вывод команды PHP `var_dump`, которая используется для дебага. Откуда оно в таком виде взялось у вас на стороне java-приложения и зачем вы его посылаете на сервер?

Comment: @rjhdby пишем приложение на os android в android studio, пользователь заполняет анкету, а мы ее отправляем на сервер. php программер дал такой кусочек кода, чтобы мы знали что и как посылать.
Когда мы посылаем просто ключ- значение  все работает
`add("project_id", "77")`
Но нам нужно отправить массив ответов

Comment: Дмитрий, отправляйте ему JSON и не парьтесь. Десереализовать JSON в массив любой сложности на PHP - это одна строка кода